# PySpark convert JSON to columns with error in dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, hive

I have a dataframe `df`

| col |
| --- |
| {"A":"ppp","B":"ee","C":"sad"........} |
| . |
| . |
| . |

I am trying to use

```
schema = StructType([StructField("a", StringType()),StructField("b", StringType())])
df = df.withColumn('col',from_json('col',schema')).select(col('col'.*)
```

However, I get the below error
due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type however col is of map<string, string> type

Comment: what does `df.printSchema()` print? Is `col` really a string column?